# getselectionmodel when using treelist not available

Tags: extjs6, extjs6-classic

I am using tree list and trying to use `getselectionmodel`but throwing error. If i use tree panel instead of tree list it works.

```
this.up('panel').getSelectionModel().getSelection();
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1fpf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tree lists are light weight - they don't have a selection model, as such. You can see the selection using the [`getSelection()` config property accessor](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0-classic/Ext.list.Tree.html#cfg-selection).